# Error when using `delete` as property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that is deleting a gallery from a database.  The code was working until a couple of weeks ago and I had other problems with it having to switch from jquery.interface to jquery-ui but now when I try to re-submit my changes to the svn I get an error. invalid property id.  the line that throws the error is this:

```
post:$("#post").val(), delete:true
```

Whole code snippet is:

```
var answer = confirm("This will permanently delete this entire gallery. Are you sure you want to proceed?");
    if (answer) {
        $.post(
            "admin-ajax.php?action=gallery_submit",
            { post:$("#post").val(), delete:true },
            function(data){
                if (data == 1) { //success
                    $('body').html('<div class="success">Your gallery has been successfully deleted.</div>');
                    setTimeout(function() { tinyMCEPopup.close(); }, 2000);
                } else { //error
                    alert('There was an error with deleting your gallery, and so, it was NOT deleted.\n\r\n\rThe following error was encountered:\r\n' + data);
                }
            }
        );
```

Did some syntax change for $.post that I have not been aware of, I checked the docs and do not see anything that matches.

Comment: You're not being very clear - is this a javascript error or a source-control error? Why do you mention committing to svn? Incidentally, I _strongly_ recommend naming your parameters to your `post` call, ala `{"data": {<blah>}, "success": function(date){/*blah*/}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete is a reserved word, so you must quote it.

```
 { post:$("#post").val(), "delete":true },
```